# random.random - random() takes no arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to have random.random choose from a list of functions in cmd_advice (i assume that's how it works?) however my debugger is showing me TypeError: random() takes no arguments (1 given).

I'm new, so I apologize if this looks stupid.

```
    # minqlbot - A Quake Live server administrator bot.
# Copyright (C) Mino <mino@minomino.org>

# This file is part of minqlbot.

# minqlbot is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.

# minqlbot is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.

# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with minqlbot. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import minqlbot
import random

class fun(minqlbot.Plugin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.add_command("cookies", self.cmd_cookies)
        self.add_command("<3", self.cmd_heart, channels=("chat", "team_chat", "tell"))
        self.add_command("wife", self.cmd_wife)
        self.add_command("advice", self.cmd_advice)

    def cmd_cookies(self, player, msg, channel):
        channel.reply("^7For me? Thank you, {}!".format(player))

    def cmd_heart(self, player, msg, channel):
        s = ("^1\r oo   oo"
             "\no  o o  o"
             "\no   o   o"
             "\n o     o"
             "\n  o   o"
             "\n   o o"
             "\n    o")
        channel.reply(s.replace("o", "\x08"))

    def cmd_wife(self, player, msg, channel):
        channel.reply("^4I love my wife more than anything in the whole wide world!")

    def cmd_advice(self, player, msg, channel):
        def advice1():
            channel.reply("This is advice1")
        def advice2():
            channel.reply("This is advice2")
        def advice3():
            channel.reply("This is advice3")
        choice = [advice2(), advice3(), advice1()]
        random.random(choice)
```

Comment: Consider writing more concise example code (e.g., `random.random([1,2,3])` demonstrates the problem) when posting. Less crud for us to sort through!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `random.choice` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)) instead of `random.random`.

Comment: @larix - that link doesn't seem to have anything to do with this answer.

Comment: `def cmd_advice(self, player, msg, channel):`
  `def advice1():`
   `channel.reply("This is advice1")`
  `def advice2():`
   `channel.reply("This is advice2")`
  `def advice3():`
   `channel.reply("This is advice3")`
  `myList = [advice2(), advice3(), advice1()]`
  `random.choice(myList)`

returns this:
http://imgur.com/mfGDjbp

Comment: @larix The issue with your code is that your `choice` list is a list of function _calls_, not functions. This results in all 3 advices being sent. Instead, make it a list of advice functions `choice = [advice2, advice3, advice1]` and call a random one `random.choice(choice)()`.

Comment: @larix notice that `[advice2(), advice3(), advice1()]` calls three functions that print something and return None. You get all 3 things printed and the list itself is `[None, None, None]`.

Comment: @MaciejGol Thank you, finally this works! I tried that last night but was using the random function in a different way and was giving me a seq msg in debugger